# Dropping a course as a master's student

Tags: education, hiring

I am planning to drop a course in my master's program as it has been really difficult for me to score well in it while looking for internships this semester.

If I don't drop it I will end up with a C in that course. I already have a B- and I don't want my GPA to drop.

How badly will it my hurt my future prospects when I am looking for jobs and internships?

Just to clarify I am a CS student and I am dropping a course related to my degree.I am doing a general CS MS in the USA.

Comment: could you add more details to your question? What field are you in? What country are you in? Generally, in the US the people that care about your transcript are graduate schools. I've only been grilled about my drops and C's by graduate programs. In CS-related jobs, most people do NOT care about drops.

Comment: For most thesis-based masters programs involving research, grades are almost at the bottom of the priority list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't involve navigating the workplace.

Answer (score 6):

> How badly will it my hurt my future prospects when I am looking for
>   jobs and internships?

For most jobs, dropping a course will have absolutely no affect on your future job prospects.

Presumably, you'll make it up later, or replace it with another course so you can get your degree.

Most employers don't care about individual courses, nor look at transcripts - and thus won't even know about the drop. I've never worked for one that cared, and as a hiring manager, I've never cared.

Comment: It should be noted that getting a job within the academic sector might have some weight. For example, a professor may ask for a transcript and see you dropped a course he likes. He might ask about it. Unless you're dropping courses frequently I can't see it as a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a C or a dropped course will have the exact same effect on future job prospects (most likely none).

However I have had experiences in interviews for co-op/intern positions where the interviewer has asked "I see you have a dropped course/weak grade here on your transcript did you have difficulty with the material?".

This is your opportunity to explain whatever it was that caused this to happen. The key to answering this question is not the excuse you come up with but how you have gained the necessary knowledge since the drop. You may have to retake this course or read some books on the topic in your free time. The interviewer wouldn't ask this type of question or care about the drop/weak grade unless the class was related to the work you are going to be doing.